# Why is my kde plot showing up as vertical lines instead of a curve?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I have been trying to make a KDE plot for data I have (frequency of chromosome start sites), and although I follow the [examples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_kde_1d.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neighbors-plot-kde-1d-py) exactly, when I use my data or generated data that looks like my own, the entire plot messes up and produces only vertical lines instead of the normal curve. I was hoping someone more familiar with scikit learn KDE could help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code with generated data from the example, where everything runs fine:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

X = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(0, 1, 14), np.random.normal(5, 1, 6)))[:, np.newaxis]
X_plot = np.linspace(-5, 10, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=1.0).fit(X) 
log_density = kde.score_samples(X_plot)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.fill_between(X_plot[:, 0], np.exp(log_density), color="b")
plt.plot(X, np.full_like(X, -0.01), '|k', markeredgewidth=.01)
ax.set_xlim(-5, 10)
```

Here is the code with data I generated to look like my data. I have 1,000 start sites in the data and they range in value from 10000 to 824989. I changed the data, the linspace range and step, and the x axis, and now I get vertical lines instead of a curve. I also changed the y limits because they turned out really weird.

```
X = np.random.normal(10000, 824989, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]
X_plot = np.linspace(10000, 824989, 100000)[:, np.newaxis]
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=1.0).fit(X) 
log_density = kde.score_samples(X_plot)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.fill_between(X_plot[:, 0], np.exp(log_density), color="b")
plt.plot(X, np.full_like(X, -0.01), '|k', markeredgewidth=.01)
ax.set_xlim(10000, 824989)
ax.set_ylim(-0.0001, 0.00061)
```

I think it must have something to do with the linspace. I don't really understand why `score_samples()` takes the linspace as a parameter either.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code:

1. The bandwidth used in the kernel density estimation needs to be higher as your data has a much larger standard deviation compared to the example (your data has a standard deviation of 824,989 while the data used in the example has a standard deviation of 2.5). You would need to use a bandwidth of approximately 200,000 instead of a bandwidth of 1. See, for instance, the section on "A rule-of-thumb bandwidth estimator" in the [Wikipedia article on Kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation).
2. The purpose of using `np.linspace()` is to generate a set of data points at which the estimated kernel density function `kde` can be evaluated. In order to be able to visualize the full distribution of your data the first argument of `np.linspace()` should be set equal to the minimum of the data (instead of the mean of the data) and the second argument of `np.linspace()` should be set equal to the maximum of the data (instead of the standard deviation of the data).

I included an example below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

mu = 10000 # mean
sigma = 824989 # standard deviation

# generate the data
X = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)[:, np.newaxis]

# estimate the optimal bandwidth
h = 1.06 * np.std(X) * (len(X) ** (- 1 / 5))

# estimate the density function
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=h).fit(X)

# evaluate the density function
x = np.linspace(np.min(X), np.max(X), 100000)[:, np.newaxis]
log_density = kde.score_samples(x)
density = np.exp(log_density)

# plot the density function
plt.plot(x, density)
```