# Plotting probability density function in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, kernel-density

I want to plot two probability density functions (pdf) based on values of a certain column in a dataframe.  The first one for all the values that correspond to rows with `target label = 0` and second one where `target label = 1`.

My attempt is below, but as you can see the curves do not look like a pdf (the max value is 0 and they are not confined to X axis in range 0-1 and 5-6.  I assume I can get something close by playing around with bw factor, but I am looking for a one-liner that just figures out right params and plots a pdf(including figuiring out the right X-axis start/end to use).  Is there any such built in function that does this. If not, would appreciate some pointers on how to build something like this.

```
#matplotloib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity

values = np.random.rand(10)
values_shift5 = np.random.rand(10) + 5
df = pd.DataFrame({'values' : values, 'label' : np.zeros(10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame({'values' : values_shift5, 'label' : np.ones(10)})])

kde_label_0 = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.5).fit(df[df.label == 0]['values'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
kde_label_1 = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=0.5).fit(df[df.label == 1]['values'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
X_plot = np.linspace(0, 10, 50).reshape(-1, 1)
log_density_0 = kde_label_0.score_samples(X_plot)
log_density_1 = kde_label_1.score_samples(X_plot)
plt.plot(X_plot, log_density_0, label='Label 0')
plt.plot(X_plot, log_density_1, label='Label 1')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot of what I get]

Comment: This is much easier with scipy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.6.0/reference/tutorial/stats.html

Comment: If you plot the actual densities (i.e. `np.exp(log_density_0)` and `np.exp(log_density_1)`) rather than the log-densities the plot will look as expected. There are numerous approaches for choosing the bandwidth of the kernel. See, for instance, the section on "A rule-of-thumb bandwidth estimator" in the [Wikipedia article on Kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation). You can also find an example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61475734/11989081